# Integral where limit of bounds both goes to infinity

Tags: improper-integrals

does the following expression goes to zero?

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} \int_{x}^{+\infty} F(x)dx$$

My thinking process is that since the bounds of the integral are converging to the same "value", it should collapse. Is this correct? Thank you!

Comment: Does $\int_a^{\infty}F(x)\mathrm{d}x$ converge for some value $a$?

Comment: What happens if $F(x)=1$?

Comment: how about a function F(x) = 1 / (x - [x]) where [x] is the floor function (largest integer less than x) then however large x is, there is always an infinity of infinite areas ahead of it - but I don't really know what the answer is supposed to be though!  I sort of think it could be unbounded, for some F(x)

Comment: If you're trying to reason along the lines that $\int_a^a f(x)\; dx=0$, then this isn't good enough.